# Getting img source link from multiple elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get a link from multiple attributes

example :

```
<img id="ucCPCItemList_rptItems_ucItemListLayout_0_itemImage1_0"
onerror="if(this.src=='http://pics.auction.co.kr/renewa/lp/img_none.gif') return; 
this.src='http://pics.auction.co.kr/renewal/lp/img_none.gif';"
imageresizeonload="False" blockadultitems="True" 
src="http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/12/5c/c6/125cc6ccc2.jpg" 
style="height:130px;width:130px;" width="130">
```

There are three image sources in the tag but only last source has a image

So I want to take last one but I don't know how to take the last one using Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last one happens to "sit" inside the `src` tag which makes it [available directly](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
soup.find("img", id="ucCPCItemList_rptItems_ucItemListLayout_0_itemImage1_0")["src"]
```

Comment: @Minsookim BeautifulSoup's tags provide a dictionary-like access to its attributes. I've linked the documentation chapter about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the select method also

```
soup.select("img#ucCPCItemList_rptItems_ucItemListLayout_0_itemImage1_0")[0]['src']
```

Comment: you can access any attribute using ['attibute']

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = "your example"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('img').get('src'))

# Output 'http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/12/5c/c6/125cc6ccc2.jpg'
```